# Google search opens multiple windows

Tags: internet-explorer, google-search

I am doing a Google search and for some reason it when I click search it just opens up an infinite amount of new blank windows with the URL https://www.google.com/#https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy- in each window and I have to crash out of Internet Explorer.

I have a Windows 7 Professional machine with Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very weird. Try Internet options/Advanced/Restore advanced settings. If that doesn't work, try 'Reset...' on the same page. You will need to re-enable and possibly reinstall any plugins you need afterwards.

You will lose all customizations as well when using reset.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention i have already reset Ie and deleted all cookies and browsing history will try to advanced restore

Comment: Oh OK. Advanced settings restore should be included in the reset, I just said to do that first because it's less destructive.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
All the new windows had this URL

```
https://www.google.com.au/#https://www.google.com.au/search?https://www.google.com.au/search?`sclient=psy-ab&q=test
```

To resolve it I stripped the first bit of the URL out which was

```
https://www.google.com.au/#https://www.google.com.au/search?
```

When I hit enter I was prompted for Google's CAPACHA
I filled in the CODE and the problem was resolved.
Hope this helps

Comment: Please do not put a signature line in your posts. You can enter your username and a URL on your user profile by clicking on your username, then clicking "edit" on that page.